# Ubuntu 18.04 KDE: How do I fix or re-install KDE System Monitor 15.12.9 (KSysGuard)?

Tags: 18.04, kde, system-monitor

The battery of my laptop no longer holding charge, when the power cord was kicked out a day ago I was forced to restart it.

After restarting (operating system Ubuntu 18.04 KDE), I immediately started KDE System Monitor 15.12.9 (KSysGuard) and received an error message: "The file /home/username/.local/share/ksysguard/ProcessTable.sgrd does not contain valid XML."

I clicked this away and System Monitor opened, but only with one tab (System Load). Normally it opens with two, the other being the "Process Table".

How can I repair System Monitor, or, failing that, un-install and re-install it?

2022-04-09 Update: As per the suggestion of Archisman Panigrahi (see below), I tried removing the configuration files, which had no effect when I then re-opened System Monitor. I then uninstalled and reinstalled System Monitor:

username@username-Latitude-E6510:~$ rm -rf /home/username/.local/share/ksysguard/
username@username-Latitude-E6510:~$ sudo apt remove ksysguard
[sudo] password for username:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
libcapi20-3 libcapi20-3:i386 libfaudio0 libfaudio0:i386 libgsm1:i386 liblcms2-2:i386 libmpg123-0:i386 libxslt1.1:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED
ksysguard kubuntu-desktop
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 2 to remove and 3 not to upgrade.
After this operation, 729 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 249542 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing kubuntu-desktop (1.370) ...
Removing ksysguard (4:5.12.9-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
username@username-Latitude-E6510:~$ sudo apt install ksysguard
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
libcapi20-3 libcapi20-3:i386 libfaudio0 libfaudio0:i386 libgsm1:i386 liblcms2-2:i386 libmpg123-0:i386 libxslt1.1:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed
ksysguard
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 3 not to upgrade.
Need to get 166 kB of archives.
After this operation, 686 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 ksysguard amd64 4:5.12.9-0ubuntu0.1 [166 kB]
Fetched 166 kB in 0s (592 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package ksysguard.
(Reading database ... 249533 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../ksysguard_4%3a5.12.9-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ksysguard (4:5.12.9-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up ksysguard (4:5.12.9-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
username@username-Latitude-E6510:~$ sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED
libcapi20-3 libcapi20-3:i386 libfaudio0 libfaudio0:i386 libgsm1:i386 liblcms2-2:i386 libmpg123-0:i386 libxslt1.1:i386
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 8 to remove and 3 not to upgrade.
After this operation, 2,248 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 249539 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libcapi20-3:amd64 (1:3.27-3) ...
Removing libcapi20-3:i386 (1:3.27-3) ...
Removing libfaudio0:amd64 (19.07-0~bionic) ...
Removing libfaudio0:i386 (19.07-0~bionic) ...
Removing libgsm1:i386 (1.0.13-4build1) ...
Removing liblcms2-2:i386 (2.9-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing libmpg123-0:i386 (1.25.10-1) ...
Removing libxslt1.1:i386 (1.1.29-5ubuntu0.2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.5) ...
username@username-Latitude-E6510:~$

Starting System monitor afterward, I again get the same error message:

"The file /home/username/.local/share/ksysguard/ProcessTable.sgrd does not contain valid XML."

Clicking that away, it opens again without the Process Table tab.

Any idea how I might sort the XML of the file /home/username/.local/share/ksysguard/ProcessTable.sgrd?

In another forum, I see a (OpenSuse 13.2 and KDE 4.14.1) user with a similar problem reinstalled ksysguard, also to no avail, and was advised to:

"try stopping ksysguard and renaming ~/.kde[4]/share/apps/ksysguard then restart it".

This rectified the problem for that user. Any idea if that might work for me, and - if so - how I would carry it out?

Comment: Try removing the configuration files `rm -rf /home/username/.local/share/ksysguard/`. To uninstall ksysguard, `sudo apt remove ksysguard`, and to reinstall, `sudo apt install ksysguard`

Comment: Thank you very much Archisman Panigrahi. I followed those steps, but no change, alas (I have updated the question to show steps taken).

Comment: @Dobhran, be sure, that you replace `username` with your real user name. I made that error and `rf` did not complain for non-existing folder.